# Read text file into list of list without extra white space or '\n'

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a text file into a list of list. When it reads the list, which has words separated by commas, the list has '' and '\n' at the end. I've added strip() but it only removes the '\n'.

```
    with open("tasks.txt",'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip().split(',')
        if word[0] == username:             
            view_list.append(word)
```

The loop works except that at the end of the list it adds : , ''

Text file has lines of text as follows:

```
admin, Register Users , Use taskManager, 10 Oct 2019,25 October 2021,No,

admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No,
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: See [ask]. We need [mcve]

Comment: Please show a fragment of tasks.txt

Comment: Anyway, seems like you are dealing with CSV. If so, use the `csv` module as it will do most of the heavyliftting for you

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma after the last word so it will always append to the list the word after that comma.
Maybe if you try to check if the last word is empty it doesnt append to the list.

Like:

```
if word[0] == username and word != '':             
        view_list.append(word)
```

split(separator, maxsplit)

Seperator - Optional. Specifies the separator to use when splitting the string. By default any whitespace is a separator

Maxsplit - Optional. Specifies how many splits to do. Default value is -1, which is "all occurrences"

Maybe you can try use the maxsplit in someway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Max split won't work considering that I loop through the text.file. The != '  ' causes the if statement to be negative. 

I ended up using your != suggestion in the export as a work around when exporting it back into the text file. I used the following code (x being the iterator):

if x != '' and x != '\n':